# Google Ads app engagement campaign doesn't work with Firebase Dynamic Link

Tags: deep-linking, google-ads-api, firebase-dynamic-links, ios-universal-links, android-app-links

I'm trying to run app engagement campaign with Firebase Dynamic Links, but I receive an issue 'The link won't work because Google Ads doesn't support third-party redirect URLs. Replace it with a supported link type`.

Do you know how to apply dynamic links with Google Ads app engagement campaign?

Comment: It can be related to checking: "Skip the app preview page (not recommended)"

It's when you are setting up dynamic links on firebase console. I'll update when the warning disappears.